# Reusing Ecore model componets

Tags: code-generation, reusability, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore, mda

is there a way to reuse EMF-Ecore model components in another Ecore model?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can import one ECore model into another ECore model.

How to do this depends on the editor you use. For XCore you simply import the fully qualified name of the ECore class.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of reuse is creating virtual view models from one or many input models. Just check [EMF Views](https://github.com/atlanmod/emfviews) project for that.